# Change Font color of textfield input via JCheckBox

Tags: java

I'm making an address book and I'd like for the user to be able to color code their contacts [such as all 'friends' are printed in blue font, all family are green, etc.] I added checkboxes and I'm adding action listeners. However, I am getting a compilation error.

```
    friend = new JCheckBox("Friend");
    coWorker = new JCheckBox("Business");
    family = new JCheckBox("Family");
    miscellaneous = new JCheckBox("Miscellaneous");


jPanel4.add(friend);
    jPanel4.add(coWorker);
    jPanel4.add(family);
    jPanel4.add(miscellaneous);

    HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
    friend.addItemListener(handler);
    coWorker.addItemListener(handler);
    family.addItemListener(handler);
    miscellaneous.addItemListener(handler);


jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
            AddressBookMain.addEntry(new AddressBook(jTextField1.getText(), jTextField2.getText(), jTextField3.getText(), jTextField4.getText()));
        }
    });

`private class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        jTextField1.setFont(Color.BLUE);

    }

}`
```

Comment: What compilation error do you get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JTextField does not have a setFont method that takes a color. I think you are looking for `jTextField1.setForeground(Color.BLUE);`

Comment: Great! Btw, I think you in that case should mark the question as answered (I thinkg it's done by ticking on something next to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

jTextField1.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

Works great!